# Swap all Integers of a List with Scala

Tags: scala, list, loops, integer, swap

If I have a swap method, which can swap two Integers in a List:

```
def swap[E]: (List[E], Int, Int) => List[E] = (ls, i, j) => 
  ls.updated(i, ls(j)).updated(j, ls(i))
```

And now I want to swap all Integers of a list using this method. That means the result should be like this:

```
swapAll(List(1,2,3)) == List(List(2,1,3), List(3,2,1), List(1,3,2))
```

I thought of something like this:

```
def swapAll: List[Int] => List[List[Int]] = ls => for(i <- 0 to ls.length; j <- i to ls.length) yield List(swap(ps, i, j))
```

But it doesn't work, does somebody have an Idea?

Comment: you don't get all the permutations this way (compare with List(1,2,3).permutations.filter(l=>l!=List(1,2,3)).toSeq) - is that intentional?

Comment: I don't want to get all the permutations, it's intentional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost there.

```
def swap[E](ls: List[E], i: Int, j: Int): List[E] = {
  ls.updated(i, ls(j)).updated(j, ls(i))
}


def swapAll(ps: List[Int]): List[List[Int]] = {
  val n = ps.size
  (for {
    i <- 0 until n
    j <- (i + 1) until n
  } yield swap(ps, i, j))(collection.breakOut)
}
```

Example:

```
swapAll(List(1, 2, 3))
// List(List(2, 1, 3), List(3, 2, 1), List(1, 3, 2))
```

The `breakOut` is a special explicitly inserted `CanBuildFrom`. It's necessary because without it, the type of the produced collection is some weird `IndexedSequence` derived from the `0 until n` `Range`, but you want a `List` instead.

Comment: Nice, a great use case for `breakOut`!

Comment: Thank you very much. Very elegant, but how would one do it without breakOut?

Comment: @appcodix Call `toList` in the end: `(for { ... } yield ...).toList`. But that's inefficient, because it builds an unnecessary intermediate collection that is not a `List`. Alternatively, try `(0 until n).toList` on the generator.